# Converting integer to datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, scikits

My code:

```
import datetime as dt
import scikits.timeseries as ts

ts_start_datetime= ts.Date(freq='T',year=2011,month=1,day=1,hour= 0,minute=0)
ts_end_datetime = ts.Date(freq='T',year=2011,month=12,day=31,hour=23,minute=45)

start_val = ts_start_datetime.value
#   21564001
end_val = ts_end_datetime.value
#   22089586
```

How do I convert `start_val` and `end_val` to `datetime` objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp), since your values appear to be minutes rather than seconds, first multiply them by 60:

```
start_dt = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(start_val * 60)
end_dt = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(end_val * 60)
```

If you want a UTC time instead of a local time, use `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`:

```
>>> dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(21564001 * 60)
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 1)
>>> dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(22089586 * 60)
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 31, 23, 46)
```

I'm not exactly sure why each of these are one minute after what you started with, you can always subtract 60 before the call or subtract `dt.timedelta(minutes=1)` from the end result.

Comment: I'm guessing they're inclusive -- they include the minute in which they end, rather than ending at the very start of that minute. Otherwise if one range ended and another immediately began, they'd share the start / end minute.

Comment: Thanks! F.J for the quick answer.

Comment: No problem, if this solution works you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155356) by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the answer.